# Angels on earth

Tags: malach-angel

Angels visiting earth is a common concept, which doesn't need sources.

Does anyone know the **'Physics'** behind how the angels came to earth? Did anyone read anything interesting about this topic?

1. Was there a certain geological location on the planet where they arrived/ popped out of ?
2. How did they transform from a spiritual state to a physical state? There needs to be a point in time where they transform into physical humans and back into spiritual beings.
3. Was there some sort of portal that they used as a highway between heaven and earth? Just exactly how did they 'jump' from the heaven side to earth side?

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of fallen angels? The notion of "nephillim" is spoken at length based off Parshas Noach

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/1987422/jewish/Nephilim-Fallen-Angels-Giants-or-Men.htm

Comment: I am very familiar with Nephilim. My ques was if someone can share the 'physics' behind them going from a spiritual world to a physical world.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm saying - look at the mefarshim there.

Comment: What sort of physics are you looking for? Maybe they live in the copy universe, the 13 dimensions that pop out of string theory equations, and they are composed of the supersymmetric partners of bosons. I don't think there will be any sort of Torah source that can explain things in terms of phyics?

Comment: The word Physics was in quotes. It means, I am looking for any mechanics of how they come to earth.

Comment: Not exactly an answer, but please have a look at [Rambam's description](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_1.49.3?ven=Guide_for_the_Perplexed,_English_Translation,_Friedlander_(1903)&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) of angels that have wings and how they move.

Comment: Angels entire existence is above our physical laws, so I don't see how an explanation could work in terms of nature. To us it would all seem miraculous.

Comment: Rephrase of the question: Why is the materialisation and dematerialisation of *malachim* not considered to be a *nes* (something that breaks the laws of nature)?

Comment: @MarsSojourner May I recommend a wonderful Rama on this halacha: https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.6.1. It's considered miraculous for the spiritual and the physical to be connected. Seems nogeah to your question? I also strongly recommend this article which helps explain exactly why physics is not necessarily enough to answer questions like this, in a more rigorous way: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3432275

Comment: @RabbiKaii Ty. I understand physics is not necessarily enough to answer questions like this. But, we should realise that at the end of the day, G_d does run the Universe according to the laws of Physics. Not everything is a miracle. Miracles happen rarely. The earth hanging in space might seem like a miracle, but it is not, cause it follows the laws of Physics that G_d set in place. On the other hand, water standing like a wall during the parting of the red sea was a miracle cause water doesn't stand like a wall according to the same laws of Physics that G_d put in place.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Either way, I still hold the opinion that even angels go through some sort of Physics related process when them they transform from their state to a human state.

Comment: @MarsSojourner I believe you might be basing your opinion on certain understandings of the Rambam. This is a minority opinion as far as I am aware, and the majority opinion is that the whole of creation is a miracle. Hashem recreates everything every instant from absolute nothing, meaning each instant is not connected to the instant before it intrinsically, but only by Hashem's constantly renewed decree.